# rutube parse video

Tags: php, парсер, видео

Хотелось бы узнать, как парсить видео с Rutube чтобы получать превьюшку, название и описание видео. Нашел только этот пример, но он не работает/устарел: https://bezumkin.ru/sections/blog/441/

Comment: http://dev.rutube.ru

Answer (score 0):

FORK by PHP Video URL Parser 
Там есть и rutube в том числе. Хотя прямых ссылок не дает :(

https://github.com/Maksclub/php-video-url-parser